# Static sounds every 20-30 seconds when playing HDMI

Tags: 11.10, pulseaudio, hdmi

When I play a movie on my TV through HDMI, I hear periodic short static sounds. This happens with all players in Ubuntu, so this is not a problem with the player. When I play a movie through HDMI in Windows the audio is fine, so this is not a hardware problem. I managed to set VLC to using ALSA from its preferences dialog, and I know that for sure because my volume control icon became disabled. But VLC's audio was working great, static sounds were gone, and additionally some audio sync issues I had with VLC were gone when using ALSA.

So are those problems all connected to pulseaudio, and how can I force VLC not to use it and use ALSA instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out pulseaudio can indeed be suspended with the [pasuspender](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pasuspender) command, which is included by default in Ubuntu. That fixed the problem with the static sounds so pulseaudio was the culprit.